# React Django Auth

Tags: python, reactjs, django, axios

I'm trying to login thru ReactJS app and here is the error I get:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/auth/login/' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
> value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
> is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

even though I added `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS: True` to the `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "corsheaders",
    'rest_framework',
    'service_get_data',
    'background_task',
    'service_append_data',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
#         'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
#     )
# }

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS: True
```

And here is the Axios request:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/login', {username: username, password:password}, {withCredentials: true})
            .then(r => {console.log(r)})
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
              });
```

And here are the requests sent:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours and hours it turned out to be a stupid mistake I was doing:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS: True
```

Instead of:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written MIDDLEWARE in wrong order ,the correct order in your case would be
`MIDDLEWARE = [

```
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]`

Comment: I added a new answer ! Try it it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can solve this issue with django-cors-headers**

1. **Install it in the env** : `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. **Configure the settings**

> Add `corsheaders` to the INSTALLED_APPS

> Add `CorsMiddleware` above `CommonMiddleWare` in `MIDDLEWARE`

> Create a `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`

Example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # Others middleware here
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000', # For react front end
    'http://localhost:8000', # For Django
)
```

**NB :** It’s very important that `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` appears in the proper location. That is above `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE` setting
since `middlewares` are loaded top-to-bottom.
Also note that we whitelisted two domains:
`localhost:3000` and `localhost:8000` . The former is the default port for React, which we will use for our front-end. The latter is the default Django port.

Comment: Moving `CorsMiddleware` was already suggested by another user and it didn't work other than that did you see my `settings.py` everything you said I already did.

Comment: Try with this instead : `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` (Need to comment the line `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`) and set also `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`